# MySQL data type tinyint(4)

Tags: mysql, database

I need to know what this number in parentheses refer to

[image]

Comment: It refers to the length in bytes.

Comment: That's awfully big for a "tiny" int.

Answer (score 0):

For integer numbers it's how many places to pad to, serving mostly as a hint, as [integer sizes are fixed based on type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html). For strings it's a hard limit on how many characters that field can contain.

For example, an `INT(4)` field can contain any number an `INT` can, though the intent is to contain only four digit numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE example (ivalue INT(4));

INSERT INTO example VALUES (999999999);
```

This works without issue:

```
+-----------+
| ivalue    |
+-----------+
| 999999999 |
+-----------+
```

For [fixed point types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) the numbers have more significant meaning.